# MFC: how to change default file name for CFileDialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

When a user chooses "Save", I want the save file dialog to use a suggested file name other than the default "Untitled". Below is the code I am testing.

```
BOOL CMRCDoc::DoSave(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bReplace)
{
    CFileDialog file_dialog(false);

    file_dialog.m_ofn.lpstrFile = _T("my_file_name");
    if (file_dialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        OnSaveDocument(file_dialog.GetPathName());
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

It has access violation during runtime from DoModal as it tries to clean up the memory.

```
INT_PTR CFileDialog::DoModal()
{
    ...

    // zero out the file buffer for consistent parsing later
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidAddress(m_ofn.lpstrFile, m_ofn.nMaxFile));
    DWORD nOffset = lstrlen(m_ofn.lpstrFile)+1;
    ASSERT(nOffset <= m_ofn.nMaxFile);
    memset(m_ofn.lpstrFile+nOffset, 0, (m_ofn.nMaxFile-nOffset)*sizeof(TCHAR));

    ...
}
```

So what is the right way to change the default file name for the file dialog?

Comment: `file_dialog.m_ofn.lpstrFile = _T("my_file_name");` This is wrong, twice so. (i) You pass a pointer to a read-only buffer, while OPENFILENAME expects a writable buffer. (ii) You don't set nMaxFile to the size of the buffer, expected to be at least 256 chars. See the docs for [CFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2019) and [OPENFILENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew).

Comment: Or just set the file name in `CFileDialog`, then you don't have to allocate memory. You can also set the file extension. `CFileDialog dlg(false, _T("txt"), _T("My file"), OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, _T("Text files|*.txt|All files|*.*||")); dlg.DoModal();`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, works great, thank you so much for the help!