# MFC: how to differentiate "Save" vs "Save As"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

In my previous question ([MFC: how to change default file name for CFileDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919613/mfc-how-to-change-default-file-name-for-cfiledialog)), I overload `DoSave` function to supply a file name suggestion. Within this function is there way to differentiate "Save" vs "Save As"? Because I should only pop out dialog window if it is "Save As".

```
BOOL CMyDoc::DoSave(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bReplace)
{
    if (IsSaveAS() || m_saved_file_name.IsEmpty())
    {
        CString file_name = some_suggested_file_name;

        CFileDialog file_dialog(false, ..., file_name, ...);

        if (file_dialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
        {
            m_saved_file_name = file_dialog.GetPathName();
        }
    }

    OnSaveDocument(m_saved_file_name);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog should be popped when `lpszPathName == NULL || *lpszPathName == '\0'`.

This covers the case where `DoSave` is called from `OnFileSaveAs`:

```
void CDocument::OnFileSaveAs()
{
    if(!DoSave(NULL))
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: File save-as failed.\n");
}
```

And also the case where the associated file is read-only and cannot be written to.

```
BOOL CDocument::DoFileSave()
{
    DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(m_strPathName);
    if (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
    {
        // we do not have read-write access or the file does not (now) exist
        if (!DoSave(NULL))
        {
            TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: File save with new name failed.\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!DoSave(m_strPathName))
        {
            TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: File save failed.\n");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

It also matches the logic of the builtin `DoSave`.

```
BOOL CDocument::DoSave(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bReplace)
    // Save the document data to a file
    // lpszPathName = path name where to save document file
    // if lpszPathName is NULL then the user will be prompted (SaveAs)
    // note: lpszPathName can be different than 'm_strPathName'
    // if 'bReplace' is TRUE will change file name if successful (SaveAs)
    // if 'bReplace' is FALSE will not change path name (SaveCopyAs)
{
    CString newName = lpszPathName;

    if (newName.IsEmpty())
    {
        // ...
        if (!AfxGetApp()->DoPromptFileName(newName,
    // ...
```